# Pyspark - Loop over dataframe columns by list

Tags: pyspark

New to pyspark. Just trying to simply loop over columns that exist in a variable list. This is what I've tried, but doesn't work.

```
column_list = ['colA','colB','colC']
for col in df:
   if col in column_list:
      df = df.withColumn(...)
   else:
      pass
```

It's definitely an issue with the loop. I feel like I'm missing something really simple here. I performed the df operation independently on each column and it ran clean ie.

```
df = df.withColumn(...'colA').withColumn(...'colB').withColumn(...'colC')
```

Comment: The error points to a bool issue in the logic which goes inside the `withColumn`. Do update question with the logic for the columns.

Comment: How can that be? If the alternative solution works then it can't be the logic, right? All I'm doing is literally substituting col for the actual field names in the loop

Comment: Can you provide the full code that produces the error? ie where the ......'s are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following snippet

```
column_list = ['colA','colB','colC']
for col in df.columns:
   if col in column_list:
      df = df.withColumn(....)
   else:
      pass
```